# How to estimate the probability distribution of the next point in a time series if the autocorrelation function is known

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, correlation, autocorrelation

Let's consider a time-series $\{X_i\}_{i\in [1, N]}$ such that $X_i, X_j$ identically distributed as priori but are not necessarily indepedent.
In fact, let's consider the [two-point correlation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ursell_function)
$$
g_X(i-j) = E(X_i  X_j) - E(X_i)E(X_j).
$$
Let's suppose that $g(x)$ has the form of $e^{-\tau x}$ where $\tau$ is a finite, nonzero real number.

Suppose that we know the function $g_X$ and observed the random variable $X_1$ and learned it has the outcome $x_1$.

how can we use the knowledge of $g_X$ to derive a probability distribution for $X_2$ given that we know that outcome of $X_1$ is $x_1$?

---

**Addendum:**

The motive behind this question is the following:

In physics, for instance, we typically look at the two-point correlation between two time-series and if the two-point correlation for at least one-time lag is *significantly* higher, then we say that these two-time series are correlated with a time lag...

So, calculating the two-point correlation function helped us whether these two-time series are correlated or not (binary information), but if I want to know more about one of the time series only by observing the other time series, a binary correlated-not-correlated doesn't provide me with any quantitative information. I want to be able to use the two-point correlation function and observe only one of the time series in order to make quantitative inferences on the other time-series.

Comment: What you have in the equation looks like covariance rather than correlation.

Comment: What you described is not a statistical hypothesis testing problem.  Otherwise, where are null and alternative hypotheses?

Comment: Can you be more explicit in what you mean by "$X_{i},X_{j}$ are identically distributed", given that you mention an autocorrelation function? What are you asking after when you say "estimate the probability distribution of the next point in a time series" if the next point is already stated to be identically distributed?

Comment: Also: Welcome to CV, Our!

Comment: What you anticipated is too ambitious.  It is like asking for determining the distribution of $X$ with the only condition is the variance of $X$, which is unrealistic (for example, both $N(0, 1)$ and $\text{Exp}(1)$ have variance $1$, how would I choose between them?).  In addition, it's not that accurate to say "derive a probability distribution", as it's not the correct logic in statistical inference (in contrast with math proofs).  Given the observed data and some population information, at best you can say "fit the distribution after specifying (i.e., modeling) one".

Comment: @Alexis, Our has been a member of CV for 4 years, 7 months. But it is never too late to welcome people :)

Comment: @RichardHardy exactly! ;)

Comment: @Zhanxiong as a priori, yes I assume that both $X_i$ and $X_j$ are identically distributed. Please also see my addendum.